# Python Regex expression

Tags: python, regex

Trying to write a Regex expression in Python to match strings.

I want to match input that starts as `first`, `first?21313` but not `first.`

So basically, I don't want to match to anything that has `.` the period character.

I've tried `word.startswith(('first[^.]?+'))` but that doesn't work. I've also tried `word.startswith(('first.?+'))` but that hasn't worked either. Pretty stumped here

Comment: Don't make `[^.]` optional with `?`.

Comment: `str.startswith()` takes literals - not regular expressions... look into importing and using the actual `re` and its `.match` method...

Answer (score 1):

```
 import re  
 def check(word):
        regexp = re.compile('^first([^\..])+$')
        return regexp.match(word)
```

And if you dont want the dot:
^first([^..])+$
(first  + allcharacter except dot and first cant be alone).

Comment: How do I do this with `startswith`? When I tried, it gave me issues?

Comment: why do you want do it with startswith?, if you have a lot of checks and you want do it in only one line, you can create method like: check(word,regexpParam) and re.compile(refexpParam) and you change: word.startswith(('first[^.]?+')) for check(word,'^first([^\..])+$')

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need regex for this at all.

```
word.startswith('first') and word.find('.') == -1
```

But if you really want to take the regex route:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r'first[^.]*$', 'first')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 5), match='first'>
>>> re.match(r'first[^.]*$', 'first.') is None
True
```

Comment: There are a lot of edge cases and allowable values, `first.stuffafter` being one. So that definitely won't work EDIT: didn't see your edit in time. Looks like the other answer and I'll try testing

Comment: @simplycoding What output are you expecting from `first.stuffafter`? Do you expect a list in the form of ['first', 'stuffafter']? Do you expect two capture groups from the match that contains the text?